# Login Handling in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, authentication, backbone.js

i need a very simple login system for my web application with backbone.js

Workflow:
App Start -> LoginView -> When Logged In -> App

Here is my solution. What can i do better?

**Login Status Model:**

```
window.LoginStatus = Backbone.Model.extend({
defaults: {
    loggedIn: false,
    userId: null,
    username: null,
    error: "An Error Message!"
},

initialize: function () {
    _.bindAll(this, 'getSession', 'setStorage');
},

getSession: function (username, password) {
    var tmpThis = this;
    $.getJSON('http://requestURL.de/getSession.php?username=' + username + '&password=' + password, function(data) {
        if (data != null) { 
            tmpThis.setStorage(data.id, data.username);
            $.mobile.changePage("#home");
        }                                   
    });
},
setStorage: function(userId, username) {
    localStorage.setItem("userId", userId);
    localStorage.setItem("username", username);
    this.set({ "loggedIn" : true});
}
});
```

**Here is my Login View:**

```
window.LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({

el: $("#login"),

initialize:function () {
    this.render();
},

events: {
    "click input[type=submit]": "onSubmit"
},

onSubmit: function(event) {
        var username = $(this.el).find("#user-username").val(),
            password = $(this.el).find("#user-password").val();

        this.model.getSession(username, password);

        return false;
},
render:function () {
    if (this.model.get("loggedIn")) {
        var template = _.template( $("#login_template").html(), {} );
    } else {
        var template = _.template( $("#login_template").html(), { "error" : this.model.get("error") } );
    }
    $(this.el).html( template );
}

});
```

Comment: It may not be important for your app, but this approach is pretty insecure.

Comment: If you're looking for general feedback on your code, http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is probably more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion to you is making the login outside the backbone app and only after a success login process let them access the "single page app"

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this backbone project which does the login request using POST method. https://github.com/denysonique/backbone-login